# push to list based mongodb

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

I would like to update the following structure:

```
record = {'_id':some_id,
          'status':  { 1 : {
                              'events' : [a,b,c ],    
                              'other_stuff' : { }
                             }

                     { 2 : {
                             'events' :  [a,b,c ] },    
                             'other_stuff' : { } 
                            } ,
                     }
          ,
          'other_key':{...}
          }
```

Now what I want to do is, with status code = 3 and and event list = ['x','y','z'] I would like to have:

```
record = {'_id':some_id,
         'status':  { 1 : {
                              'events' : [a,b,c],    
                              'other_stuff' : { }
                             },

                     { 2 : {
                             'events' :  [a,b,c ] },    
                             'other_stuff' : { } 
                            } ,
                     { 3 : {
                             'events' :  [x,y,z ] },    

                            } ,
                     }
          ,'other_key':{...}
          }
```

Is there a fast way to get this done without too much maneuvering?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [dot notation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/document/#document-dot-notation) to [specify the embedded document](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/set/#set-fields-in-embedded-documents) in your **[`$set`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/set/#set)** as follows:

```
db.collection.updateOne(
    { "_id": ObjectId("5852bc9eade47a3353ff01d0") },
    { 
        "$set": {
            "status.3": {
                "events" : ["x","y","z"]
            }
        } 
    }
)
```

Comment: How about `"$set":  { "status.3.events" : ["x","y","z"] }`?